# Usemap hook is not working in react leaflet TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, leaflet

Leaflet to complete a challenge, but for some reason it is not working and throwing an error. This is the error:

```
Error: No context provided: useLeafletContext() can only be used in a descendant of <MapContainer>
```

And when I try removing it and replace it with `useLeafletContext` it is not defined.

This is the code:

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, useMap } from 'react-leaflet';
const Map: React.FC<MapProps> = ({ cords }) => {
    const map = useMap();
    const handleChange = (value: string, type: keyof Coordinates) => {
        setCoordinates((prevCoordinates) => ({
            ...prevCoordinates,
            [type]: Number(value),
        }));
        map.setView([lat, long])
    };
}
```

I have the rest of the code but this is where the error is.
I saw other forms, but it did it wokr, and I need to use react-leaflet.
NOTE: it is in typescript

Comment: You are misusing contexts. Your `<Map />` component needs to be a direct child of a `<MapContainer>`. How are you rendering your `Map`?

Comment: this way @nbokmans:
```js
<MapContainer
        center={[lat, long]}
        zoom={12}
        className="w-full h-[70%] absolute bottom-0"
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={[lat, long]}>
          <Popup>This is your current location</Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by creating a separate component for it this is the code for the other component:

```
import { TileLayer, Marker, Popup, useMap  } from "react-leaflet";
type Coordinates = {
    lat: number;
    long: number;
  }
  
type props = {
    cords: Coordinates;
}
export function ReactMarker({cords}: props){
    const map = useMap()
    map.setView([cords.lat, cords.long])
    return(
        <section>
            <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            <Marker position={[cords.lat, cords.long]}>
                <Popup>This is your current location</Popup>
            </Marker>
        </section>
    )
}
```